# Strip of all tags "Defer[...]" from a string expression

Tags: string-manipulation

How can i remove all "Defer[...]" from the following expression

```
 "Table[Times[Rational[-1, 12], Kx, Power[Lc, -1], Power[lp, -1], \
\\[Gamma], \\[Theta], Plus[Times[3, Plus[Times[-1, ax], bx], Plus[ax, \
bx], Defer[Part[n0, k]], Defer[Part[n0, l]]], Times[-3, Power[bx, 2], \
Defer[Part[delta, k, l]]], Times[Plus[Times[Power[bx, 2], Plus[i1, \
Times[-1, i4]]], Times[Power[ax, 2], i4]], Defer[Part[INVcx, k, \
l]]]], Plus[Times[Power[bx, 2], Plus[i1, Times[-1, i4]]], \
Times[Power[ax, 2], i4], Times[3, Lc, Plus[Times[2, Lc], Times[-3, \
Rbar]], Power[Det[F], Rational[2, 3]]]], Power[Plus[Times[Power[bx, \
2], Plus[i1, Times[-1, i4]]], Times[Power[ax, 2], i4], Times[4, Lc, \
Plus[Lc, Times[-2, Rbar]], Power[Det[F], Rational[2, 3]]]], -1], \
Power[Det[F], Rational[-2, 3]]],{k,3},{l,3}]"
```

Comment: You want to do this to a string? Why not an expression?

Comment: `StringReplace[yourstring, "Defer[" ~~ Shortest[s__] ~~ "]" :> s]`, but @JohnDoty has a good point; it would be easier to do to an expression.

Comment: If it's really an expression you can just `expression /. Defer -> Identity`.  If you really need to do it to a string it will be trickier because you'll have to parse the `[matching brackets]` correctly.

Comment: @MarcoB that is not a generic solution.  Consider running it on eg. "Defer[foo[a, b[bar],c]]".

Comment: It also seems that your string, treated as an expression, produces a 3x3 matrix with each element the same.  I suspect there's a deeper underlying question from some other misunderstanding.

Comment: @JohnDoty I tried ...i used string//ToExpression//.Defer->Identity but still i could not get rid of Defer

Comment: @evanb thats why i wanted to first define my tensors and then use //ToExpression on the corrected expression

Comment: @MarcoB thank you so much

Comment: `//.` is not `/.`

Comment: @JohnDoty I know but in this very case it does not make any difference.

Comment: `/.Defer->Identity` works fine for me.

Comment: @JohnDoty do you get tensors with indicial notation (e.g., delta[[k,l]]) or you get (delta[[1,1]]) ?

Comment: This seems like it may be an XY problem. Are you certain it isn't? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I can't help but wonder: Why do you have a string in the first place? Why are you using Defer (it's misused extremely often)?

Comment: I get `delta[[k,l]]`, since I haven't defined `k` or `l`.

Comment: You're `Table`ing over `k` and `l`... they don't need to be previously defined.

Comment: @JohnDoty Look at the beginning and end of the 
 string expression. i have already defined the loop using the table command. Please use the code MarcoB suggested and see the difference.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have developed an autoloop command for the expression of this form (a[i,j] a[k,l])